# weather resistant wood board on loggia

Tags: wood, outdoor, weather-resistant

**I have a loggia** (=balcony where the sides are closed so that weather can only come from the open front).

**I want to put a board with short legs on the side of it** (like a very low table, around 30cm high). The purpose of the board is

- to store my foldaway chairs on top,
- to protect the area below from sunlight and precipitation, so that I can store stuff below (I will put the stuff into plastic boxes so that a little water is no issue.)

Background: I wanted to use wall cupboards to store my stuff, but my landlord forbids anything high above the parapet height for aesthetic reasons. So I'm going to use the ground for storage without making the usable space smaller; i.e. the chairs that currently stand on the side of the loggia, on the ground, just move upwards a bit.

**The board should stay there invariably**, which means here **in Germany**

- sun will shine on it for some hours each day
- it can get moist due to general air moisture (especially in autumn where it can be foggy)
- it can get wet due to rain
- it can become covered in snow
- the snow can melt and freeze alternately, so that a layer of ice / snow slush will cover it for several days

Since it is a loggia, rain and snow will not hit it very often (only when wind blows the precipitation onto the loggia), but they will happen. Let's say around 10 times a year.

**I would like to know what kind of wood I should use and/or how to prepare it for that usage.** Like:

- Should I use a board that is already water-repellant like a melamin-coated one?
- Should I use uncoated wood and prepare it accordingly (oiling, glazing, ...)?

I do not mind needing to maintain the board once a year (like reapplying some coating), but not more often. Especially it should not be necessary to wipe away water after each rain-/snowfall. Looks don't matter, but of course I do not want to grow mold or bugs on/inside the board, and the board should stay there for at least 5 years.

Comment: I would not use wood, I would use plastic boards

Comment: @Ruskes I would, too, if there was a shop selling stable plastic boards in custom sizes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your project I recommend **Floor Boards** made of Vinyl (plastic), since you will not walk or sit on it, they are strong enough for your chair storage.

Perfect for outdoor weather, wont rot, no need to paint, very easy to clean.

If you take the **click** type they click together forming a continuous surface. You can easy cut them with Utility knife to desired length.

[image: click]

You can get them on Amazon.de

Exmaple here: [Amazon.de](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Artens-PVC-Parent/dp/B08TJ13Q56/ref=sr_1_2?crid=5O7H0M92DQZS&keywords=vinylbodenbelag%2Bklick%2B5%2Bmm%2Bdick&qid=1659549854&sprefix=vinyl%2Bflooring%2Bclick%2B5%2Bmm%2Bthick%2Caps%2C247&sr=8-2&th=1)

Now we need 30 cm high frame. You could simply use some bricks for that, or construct the frame.

If you choose the deck boards, know that you will have large gaps between them that will let the rain true.

With the CLICK boards you do not have the gaps.

Answer (score 3):

Go see what's available for **deck boards** at your local suppliers. That will typically include plastic composite lumber, naturally weather resistant woods like Ipe, and un-naturally weather resistant (pressure-treated) woods. Possibly other materials as well.

They will have varying costs and (if you care about that) appearances.

Despite the "somewhat sheltered" location, your best bet is to select something that is expected to be fine if out in the weather all the time, since it will be out in the weather to an extent.

While checking local suppliers, check if any of them will cut those to length for you (possibly for an additional fee,) since you mention in a comment needing "custom sizes." Or buy an inexpensive saw (a hand-saw should be quite adequate for the project you detail) and a square and Do It Yourself.